Invalid arguments error when calling program method via anchor
I am trying to call a program method using anchor. I have the idl.json, I initialize the program and then i call the method. I do it through this:
const program = new Program(idl as Idl, programId, provider);
const aToB = await program.methods.foo({
    x: 2
    })
    .accounts({tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID});

But i get the following error:
/Users/joe/code/tutorial/node_modules/.pnpm/@coral-xyz+anchor@0.26.0/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/program/common.js:39
                throw new Error(`Invalid arguments: ${acc.name} not provided.`);
                      ^

Error: Invalid arguments: tokenProgram not provided.

However, i am providing tokenProgram. Looking at the error and digging further - i found that the call ctx does not have tokenProgram even though I passed it.
What am i doing wrong ?
